# Lift Session expires

Tags: session, lift

I am new to lift and trying to write a simple login application. When I leave my login page for some time, and I enter username and password it doesn't login instead it perform session expire behavior.
I checked the log and found that whenever I got `INFO -  Session navoo0xdu1ia1vi8m1c0cnl3w expired`  log message, the above behavior happens.

I am not able to understand why request is using the existing session, even if it's already expired. Please guide me where can I found documentation/example/tutorial to understand this behavior and how to implement simple session based login functionality.

Any help will be appreciated since this problem is bottleneck to me. I googled a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

If your session is expiring then it is because of one of two things:

1) The value set in LiftRules.sessionInactivityTimeout

or

2) The value set for session expiry within your container session.

The former is actually set to nothing by default, which means the latter will override it. Be aware however that provided you are interacting with Lift and have not disabled the heartbeat pulse then sessions do not expire. If you watch the AJAX traffic you will notice a page heartbeat used for function GC which keeps the page bound functions alive.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate it. I found out the problem, it was due to I was using embedded jetty and was using ServeletContextHandle to register lift filter. Lift filter doesn't work with ServletContextHandler well so I have changed it with WebAppHandler and it's working great.